# Is it worth having a crossdomain.xml file to explicitly block all access?

Tags: xml, cross-domain

I've been getting a lot of 404 errors on my site for `/crossdomain.xml`. What is the most basic example of a file that blocks all cross domain requests? Is a blank file the same as explicitly blocking all cross domain requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to make a crossdomain policy file. Websites must explicitly allow Flash via crossdomain policy, or it is completely blocked.

The `/crossdomain.xml` request you see is automatically performed by Flash when it tries to access a URL on your site.

Comment: What about a blank file? Mainly I just want to remove the errors from the error log.

Comment: A blank file won't cause any problems.